How to Link a Developer Edition Salesforce Org to a Partner Edition Org?
Hello Salesforce Community,
I need assistance with linking my Developer(free) Edition Salesforce org to our organizational-level Partner Edition org. Here are the details of my current setup and what I aim to achieve:
Developer Edition Salesforce Org:

A free Salesforce environment used for development and testing.
Contains custom configurations and data relevant to our development processes.

Partner Edition Salesforce Org:

An organizational-level Salesforce environment with extensive features tailored for Salesforce partners.
Registered and accessible through the Salesforce Partner Community.

Mainly having two questions:

Is it possible to link my developer org with own namespace to the partner console? If yes, how and detailed steps?
If 1 is not possible, is there any chance to create an additional partner developer edition org within the same partner console with separate namespace for the development and testing purpose.

Thanks for your valuable assistance!

I connected my developer org with its own namespace to the partner console. Followed this steps:
Log in to the Salesforce Partner Community.
Click Publishing.
Click the Technologies tab.
Click the Orgs tab.
Click Connect Technology, and then click Org.
Click Connect.
Enter the login credentials for the org
follow this article for more info:connect devorg to partner console


Is it possible to link my developer org with own namespace to the partner console? If yes, how and detailed steps?

No.

If 1 is not possible, is there any chance to create an additional partner developer edition org within the same partner console with separate namespace for the development and testing purpose.

Also no.

Development in the modern era is to link your namespace to your Dev Hub org, which will be your PBO, and then you'll create Scratch Orgs for development, testing, and so on.
The traditional PDO is meant to be used with First-Generation Managed Packages, and the namespace should be set in the PDO. In your current situation, a Second-Generation Managed Package would be more appropriate.

Hi, thanks for answer..But I am a beginner to the Salesforce, even I am not getting any idea on your answer also. could you please explain it more for the steps to be followed.

did you mean to follow this article "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_publish_organizations.htm"?

@Pavan See the documentation for the entire setup process.
